# Расположение виджетов для диалога

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь сделать окно обмена сообщениями как например в контакте или whats app? то есть когда line edit с кнопкой отправить, прикреплён к нижней части экрана, а на остальной части экрана отображались сообщения. дело в том, что не до конца понимаю как именно это нужно сделать. Пробовал сделать используя LinearLayout но после вставки Listview, а затем lineedit, lineedit уходит вниз за пределы экрана. Посоветуйте как лучше и правильнее расположить элементы?

Comment: Может покажите ваш код, разметку!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можешь попробовать RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/myEdit"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myEdit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Вместо EditText вставляешь разметку своего lineedit